# Select Unselect multiple select fields

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple select fields like following:

```
<select class="projects" id="projects" multiple="multiple" name="projects[]" size="10">
  <option value="1">Project 1</option> 
  <option value="2">project 2</option> 
  <option value="3">Project 3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to have the feature that after user selected, if user then click somewhere else, all selected options are going back to "unselected", how to implement this feature in Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

`$("*").click(function() { $(".projects > option").removeAttr("selected");});` Should help. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LDbsn/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .focus() or .focusin()/.focusout(), respectively.
http://api.jquery.com/?s=focus